# Concatenate string and field on a iif statement

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i have a SSRS calculated filed where i can to concatenate a string and a field. How can i use the &. What's the best way to do it?

```
=iif(Fields!TYPE.Value= "A", "participated in" &Fields!NAME.Value& "'s game",
iif(Fields!TYPE.Value= "N", "did not participate in" & Fields!NAME.Value & "'s game",
"###ERROR###"
))
```

participated in Patrick's game
or
did not participate in Patrick's game

Comment: Other than the fact that you are missing a few spaces out, what's wrong with what you have already?

Comment: Did you managed to solve it??

Comment: hi, yes it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
 =IIF(Fields!TYPE.Value= "A", "participated in" AND Fields!NAME.Value= "'s game",
    IIF(Fields!TYPE.Value= "N", "did not participate in" AND Fields!NAME.Value="'s game",
    "###ERROR###",nothing ),nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&` is the right way to go, to concatenate strings, you just missed a few spaces by the first and second `&`:

```
=IIF(Fields!TYPE.Value= "A", 
     "Participated in " & Fields!NAME.Value & "'s game",
          IIF(Fields!TYPE.Value= "N", 
              "Did not participate in " & Fields!NAME.Value & "'s game",
              "###ERROR###"
              )
      )
```